# Is there an event created when the arrow buttons are clicked on a OOB Flow Screen Component?

Tags: lightning-events, lightning-scheduler, flowscreen

In the below screenshot, is there an event created when the arrow buttons(in Red box) are clicked? We would like to customize service resource availability so we need to know if next week or previous week buttons are clicked.

For Reference - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.ls_flowscreencmp_select_srvc_appt_time.htm&type=5

[image: Salesforce Scheduler Flow Screen]